Alpha Texture Brush isn't working?
I have Blender 4.1 and I'm trying to draw on scales with a brush from Blenderkit and there's no texture visible when I brush on the object it just creates this weird bump. I tried the brush out with different strengths, I just increased it up so it's more visible in the screenshot. I followed many tutorials and nothing makes this work. I also tried other textures. I'm a beginner and I've never used it so I have to clue what to do here.



Hello please pack your image and share your file (remove the objects you don't want to share)

I added the file

There are 4 main problems you're facing:
The texture has low contrast: start with the more contrasted one, until you get confortable with the tecnique.
The model hasn't enough topology: go to subdivision surface modifier, cranck up levels to 3 and apply it (you'll get around 400k vertices).
The standard stroke method "space" is not good for this kind of job, start with Anchored or Drag Dots instead.
Start with a smaller strenght (around .25).


The main problem here is that your snake doesn't have enough topology to be sculpted, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and apply it. Also maybe use a repeatable texture, something like this:

